# How to hide list if the variable value is undefined in angular 4?

Tags: angular

Want to hide the list if it retrieves undefined from json. Can anybody help.

```
HTML file:

    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async"><span *ngIf="item?.name">{{item.name}}</span></li>
    </ul>
```

Json file:

```
    {
    "chat" : {
      "-Kss3KDwaLDpzAHUKtJN" : {
            "id" : "11",
            "name" : "Shanth",
            "message" : "Hi ..!"
            },
      "-Kss3Kc9c2Ie5IXypqNe" : {
            "id" : "12",
            "name" : "",
            "message" : "Hi .."
            },
      "-KssBwcJhkNCsxUUhsXb" : {
            "id" : "13",
            "name" : "Prasanth",
            "message" : "Hi .."
            }
     }
```

Am getting Result like as below:

```
1. Shanth
2. 
3. Prasanth
```

I don't want to show the second list. It should shown as

```
1. Shanth
2. Prasanth
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve you problem.

```
<ul>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li *ngIf="item.name"><span>{{item.name}}</span></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the if condition on li instead of span

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | async" [style.display]="item.name?'block':'none'"><span >{{item.name}}</span></li>
```

You can as well use ng-container as mentioned in one of the answers.Please look at trichetriche's answer.

Comment: Throws error as "Can't have multiple template bindings on one element."

Comment: It does,go with  trichetriche  approach as its officially recommended one

Comment: It works, but the problem is that you rely on the CSS, while it's a Javascript issue. If you use ng-container, your item won't even be displayed in the page (meaning no one will access it), while only hiding it shows it in the source.